# Minimal date interval cover algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, date, intervals

The problem involves date intervals filtered by days of week. For example, the filtered interval {2001 APR 1 - 2001 APR 30, 17} corresponds to all Mondays and Sundays between April 1 and April 30. Here is the problem: given a collection of filtered date intervals, find a minimal collection of such intervals that cover exactly the same set of dates.

Initially, I naively assumed that this can be solved by sorting the intervals by start dates and merging consecutive intervals, if possible. Here is a counterexample to this approach. Consider the date interval given by the pattern 56712345671234, where each number stands for a day of week. Assign zero-based indices to the dates in this pattern. The collection of intervals {0-2, 567}, {3-9, 1234}, {10-13, 12} is the counterexample.

Is there a well-known algorithm for this problem? Can it be solved in O(nlogn) where n is the number of input intervals?

Comment: Can you pleas provide a few concrete examples with their solutions? I find it hard to understand.